# When is a free electron caught by the ion?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

Some questions about ion and a free electron heading towards it and building (or not) of atom.

1. Must the free electron pass through the electron cloud area of the subsequent quantum level in order to be caught on that level?
2. If the kinetic energy of an electron is more than the ionization energy of an atom,
   would it pass without interaction near the ion?
3. Making analogy with Earth and asteroids – if the electron hits the center or say the nuclei will it be caught inevitably and form an atom independently what is its kinetic energy?
4. If a photon delivers the ionization energy to an atom its electron (n1) can fly away but will have almost 0 kinetic energy (I think). But an electron (n2) (free) coming near the ion with 0 kinetic energy should surely been caught and form an atom? Why n1 can escape but n2 is caught?

Answer (score 1):

1, is the kinetic energy of the e is too high it can not be caught, it could so free an other e.
2. the e hitting the center is almost not possible since the center (nucleus) is too small. theoretically it could collide with an p and form an n
3.if a photon has just enough energy to free an e i.e, ionize,  in most cases it will just go back not necessary in one step but first to outer shells, an you will have different photons. the e can not fly away, except there is another positiv ion nearby to capture it.